# Git alias with multiple command

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-amend, git-alias

After a review, i need to change some code and repush all my change code on the remote branch.

So i would like to automate on git with an alias (ex: `git repushall`) these different commands:

`git add .`
 `git commit --amend` (and ctrl + x)
 `git push --force-with-lease`

I know it's in the `.gitconfig` file

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

Add the `--no-edit` flag to the commit command to skip the editor opening.

To link commands, you could simply separate them with `;`, but as Philippe mentionned in comment, it's often more effective to chain them with `&&`, then each command will only run if the previous one returned a 0 (no error) code.

```
git config --global alias.repushall '!git add . && git commit --amend --no-edit && git push --force-with-lease'
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to pipe the command with `&&` because most of the case git return code is 0?

Comment: @Philippe No, you're right, both ways work, but it's indeed safer to link commands with `&&` to stop next commands if one fails. Editing to mention it.

Comment: @Philippe It's not "piping", it's "and'ing". Piping symbol is `|`

Comment: @phd I didn't dare to correct it myself since Philippe was already correcting *me* on the technical substance, and the context made it clear enough but... you're right :-) That being said, "and'ing" sounds (and looks) awful. And "&&ing" is probably worse.

Comment: The proper term from the logic theory and computer science is [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction).

Comment: @phd I know it's not strictly speaking "piping" (and I hesitated when writing it) but I didn't find a better word (as neither a english native speaker nor a bash native writer)